# How to export excel from sql server when meeting cannot create an instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

xp_enum_oledb_providers do not have Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 How to do?

window 2008 server 64 bit and 32 bit office and sql server 2005

```
declare @PivotList nvarchar(MAX)
declare @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
set @PivotList=(SELECT top(1)
substring((SELECT distinct ( ' [' + Company + '],' ) 
from Temp_Car_Park_Transactions t2 group by Company
FOR XML PATH( '' ) 
), 2, 1000 ) as col)

set @SQL=' select * from (select [serial_no], [Date], Company from Temp_Car_Park_Transactions)t '
set @SQL=@SQL+ 'pivot(count(serial_no) for Company in('+substring(@PivotList,1,LEN(@PivotList)-1)+'))pvt '
--exec (@SQL)

insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\Applications\Carpark\Excel\Analysis.xls;', 
    'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: I install office 2007 and ACE driver in this link

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en    However, i got the same error, what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jet is only available in a 32-bit mode. Processes running in 64-bit (such as your SQL Server) cannot use it. ACE is the 64bit replacement.

If the ACE drivers are correctly installed, change the provider section to use those.

```
 .. OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
   'Data Source=d:\Applications\Carpark\Excel\Analysis.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0', 
   'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') exec (@SQL)
```

This specific block of code assumes the file is saved in a Office Excel 2007 or higher format (XLSX).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have installed Excel 2007, but server is 64 bit and SQL server is 32 bit, finally i give up this export option to use code write into excel.